# Selenium webdriver url link combination error

Tags: python, selenium, url, webdriver, combinations

Trying to get input and combine into query in Selenium, ie:

```
url = browser.get(https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/search.php?search_type=title&value=)
t = (url) + input("Band name: ")
```

Returns;

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Is there a possibility to combine these two or anyone suggest another solution for that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/search.php?search_type=title&value=
t = (url) + input("Band name: ")

browser.get(t)
```

as the exception says , browser.get() returns nothing you cannot concatenate a "none" and string. use the above approaach . store it as url and then concatenate it and then use it in browser.get